# Pagination in laravel returning method undefined

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The pagination method returns App\Article::link undefined, any ideas? I thought this was a helper method

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Article::paginate(5);
    return view('datatypes.articles.index', compact('data'));
}
```

in my view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($data as $data)
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$data->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$data->title}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
{{ $data->links() }}
```

Comment: You're overwriting $data immediately in your loop.

Comment: Thanks @Devon so i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($data as $_data)
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$_data->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$_data->title}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
{{ $_data->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your view

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($data as $item)
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$item->title}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
{{ $data->links() }}
```